# object doesn't support this property or method error on custom class

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm still having diffculty with this issue.  I'm working with custom class modules: TimeFrame and TimeSheet.  Following are shortened versions:

```
_________________________
'TIMEFRAME CLASS MODULE
'This class records Military Time, but allows
'you to also display it in Civilian Time
Private pHours As Integer
Private pMinutes As Integer
Private pTotalMinutes As Integer

Public Property Get hours() As Integer
  hours = pHours
End Property
Public Property Let hours(Value As Integer)
  If Value >= 1 And Value <= 24 Then
     pHours = Value
  Else
     Err.Raise 9009, , "Hours Value [" & CStr(Value) & "] is not valid."
  End If
End Property
Public Property Get minutes() As Integer
  minutes = pMinutes
End Property
Public Property Let minutes(Value As Integer)
  If Value >= 0 And Value <= 59 Then
    pMinutes = Value
  Else
    Err.Raise 9010, , "Minutes Value [" & CStr(Value) & "] is not valid."
  End If
End Property

Public Property Let Initialize(str As String)
  'This property expects a string formatted like: 08:30
  Dim vhours As String
  Dim vminutes As String
  Dim arrTime() As String

  If InStr(str, Me.Delimiter) Then
    arrTime = Split(str, Me.Delimiter)
    vhours = Trim(arrTime(0))
    vminutes = Trim(arrTime(1))
    If IsNumeric(vhours) Then
       pHours = CInt(vhours)
    End If
    If IsNumeric(vminutes) Then
       pMinutes = CInt(vminutes)
    End If
  Else
    'Set to defaults
    pHours = 0
    pMinutes = 0
  End If
End Property
...

_____________________________
'TIMESHEET CLASS MODULE
Private pEmployeeID As Integer
Private pStartDate As Date
Private pEndDate As Date
Private pMonStart As TimeFrame
Private pMonEnd As TimeFrame
Private pMonBreak As Double
Private pTuesStart As TimeFrame
Private pTuesEnd As TimeFrame
Private pTuesBreak As Double
Private pWedStart As TimeFrame
Private pWedEnd As TimeFrame
Private pWedBreak As Double
Private pThursStart As TimeFrame
Private pThursEnd As TimeFrame
Private pThursBreak As Double
Private pFriStart As TimeFrame
Private pFriEnd As TimeFrame
Private pFriBreak As Double
Public Property Get EmployeeID() As Integer
    EmployeeID = pEmployeeID
End Property
Public Property Let EmployeeID(Value As Integer)
    If Value > 0 Then
           pEmployeeID = Value
    Else
         MsgBox "Employee ID " & Value & " is an incorrect value." & vbCrLf & "Employee ID must be a positive integer"
    End If

End Property
Public Property Get StartDate() As Date
  StartDate = pStartDate
End Property
Public Property Let StartDate(Value As Date)
  pStartDate = Value
End Property
Public Property Get EndDate() As Date
  EndDate = pEndDate
End Property
Public Property Let EndDate(Value As Date)
  pEndDate = Value
End Property
Public Property Get MondayStart() As TimeFrame
  Set MondayStart = pMonStart
End Property
Public Property Set MondayStart(ByRef Value As TimeFrame)
  Set pMonStart = Value
End Property
Public Property Get MondayEnd() As TimeFrame
  Set MondayEnd = pMonStart
End Property
Public Property Set MondayEnd(ByRef Value As TimeFrame)
  Set pMonEnd = Value
End Property
Public Property Get MondayBreak() As Double
  MondayBreak = pMonBreak
End Property
Public Property Let MondayBreak(Value As Double)
  pMonBreak = Value
End Property
Public Property Get TuesdayStart() As TimeFrame
  Set TuesdayStart = pTuesStart
End Property
Public Property Set TuesdayStart(ByRef Value As TimeFrame)
  Set pTuesStart = Value
End Property
Public Property Get TuesdayEnd() As TimeFrame
   Set TuesdayEnd = pTuesStart
End Property
Public Property Set TuesdayEnd(ByRef Value As TimeFrame)
   Set pTuesEnd = Value
End Property
Public Property Get TuesdayBreak() As Double
  TuesdayBreak = pTuesBreak
End Property
Public Property Let TuesdayBreak(Value As Double)
  pTuesBreak = Value
End Property
...
```

In my main Module I'm calling two subroutines one after the other.

1. I have a global variable named TimeSheetCollection which is a collection contains instances of type TimeSheet
2. First I call the subroutine ReadWeeklyTimeSheets() which sets the TimeSheetCollection object, reads in todays mailitems, and from the values obtained from the body of the mailitem we set the properties in each TimeSheet. This subroutine is working just fine.
3. Next, the subroutine named ExportTimeSheetsToDatabase() is called. I've typed several Debug.print statements that I get the error message on the Item.MondayStart and Item.MondayEnd properties: "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Main Module:

```
Sub ExportTimeSheetsToDatabase()
  Dim Item As TimeSheet
  For Each Item In TimeSheetCollection
   Debug.Print "TSCollection Count: " & TimeSheetCollection.count
   Debug.Print Item.EmployeeID & ", " & Item.StartDate & ", " & Item.EndDate
   Debug.Print Item.MondayStart  '<<< Error occurs here
   Debug.Print Item.MondayEnd
   Debug.Print "Toal Hours: " & Item.TotalWeeklyHours
  Next Item
End Sub
```

Since Item is of type TimeSheet, you can see from the Class Module above that it does contain the Get method:

```
Public Property Get MondayStart() As TimeFrame
  Set MondayStart = pMonStart
End Property
```

From my research the syntax appears correct and when I type the dot operator "." after the Item my list appears with all the properties showing.  It's not like I mispelled anything.  Please advise.

Alan

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to print out a `TimeFrame`, it's not a standard data type. You'd need to process the `TimeFrame` object and return a standard type that can be printed.

Answer (score 2):

`Debug.Print` does not work on objects. You need to use it on a property or method which returns a standard datatype. Otherwise you will always get the error "object doesn't support this property or method".

For instance, you would need something like `TimeFrame.Value` or `TimeFrame.MilitaryValue`

Possible implementations:

```
Public Property Get Value() As String
    'Returns TimeFrame TimeStamp as standard time
     Value = CDate(pHours & ":" & pMinutes)
End Property

Public Property Get MilitaryValue() as String
     'Returns TimeFrame TimeStamp as Military Time
     MilitaryValue = Format(CDate(pHours & ":" & pMinutes),"hh:nn")
End Property
```

Based upon your implementation of TimeFrame it appears to be a timestamp and a duration. With that being the case, it might make more sense to use a standard `Date` datatype. The date data type is accurate to the second and you can extract specific hour and minute information using the Hour and Minute functions. Ex:
`Hour(timeStamp)` or `Minute(timeStamp)`

You could then display the time with a simple `debug.print` which would default to standard time, but could be military time by using `Format` as shown in my `MilitaryValue` example.

Comment: Alan, I suggest you read the faq, especially the part on asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask.